# What is wrong with this toString() method?

Tags: java, tostring

I'm writing a simple sudoku solver. I have 2 Constructors, the first has a 2D array in its parameter and uses it to initialize a sudoku variable. The second one recieves a string (81 numbers in length) and initialises the 2D array with this string. Like so:

```
  public class Sudoku {
   private int sudoku[][];

   public Sudoku(int sud[][]){
    sudoku = new int[sud.length][sud.length];
    for(int i=0; i<sudoku.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<sudoku.length; j++){
            sudoku[i][j]=sud[i][j];
        }
    }
   }

   public Sudoku(String sud){
    int pos = 0;
    String character="";
    sudoku = new int[sud.length()/9][sud.length()/9];
    for(int i=0; i<sudoku.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<sudoku.length; j++){
            pos = i*sud.length()/9 + j;
            character = sud.charAt(pos)+"";
        }
    }
   }.....
```

And here is the following toString() method:

```
  public String toString(){
    String sudoOut = " ";
    for(int j = 0; j<sudoku.length; j++){
        sudoOut = sudoOut+" | ";
        for(int z = 0; z<sudoku.length; z++){
            sudoOut = sudoOut+sudoku[j][z]+" ";
            System.out.println(sudoku[j][z]);

            if(z != 0 && (z+1)%3 == 0 && z+1 < sudoku.length){
                sudoOut = sudoOut + "| ";
            }
        }
        sudoOut = sudoOut+"|\n";

        if(j != 0 && (j+1)%3 == 0 && j+1 < sudoku.length){
            sudoOut = sudoOut;
        }

    }
    sudoOut = sudoOut;
    return sudoOut;
}
```

This is the test-class:

```
  public class SudokuTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Sudoku sudoku;
    String sud =   "2500309010100040004070002080052000000000981000400030000003600720700000039030006 04";
    sudoku = new Sudoku(sud);
    System.out.println(sudoku.toString());
```

Can anyone tell me why i keep getting only zeros when i print out the string above?

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged this?

Comment: I second @OliverCharlesworth's comment, but just out of curiosity, what is `sudoOut = sudoOut;` for?

Comment: `j != 0 && (j+1)%3 == 0` makes no sense since `(0 + 1) % 3 != 0`. The `j != 0 && (j+1)%3 == 0`is then equivalent to `(j+1)%3 == 0`. There are many flaws just like this one in your logic.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, the debug just showed that the values of the string were not being passed on to the sudoku. 

@HovercraftFullOfEels, i had small methods written to make the output more aesthetic. Methods that would just output `========` And i omitted this when posting the question. So it was `sudoOut = sudoOut+topLine()`

Comment: @Dici, how is that a flaw? Its an AND. Why would the second statement be tested if the first one is already false? The second statement `(j+1)%3`will only be tested if the the first one were true.

Comment: @TonyOkoth I just meant that the first test is pointless since your formula is of the form `a && b` such as `a && b <=> b`. Your condition is logically redundant, even if Java exits a conjunction test at the first failed test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you posted your full code, but in your second constructor - `Sudoku(String sud)` - you never assign anything to the `soduku` array. You only instantiate it.

I'm assuming you intended something like this :

```
   public Sudoku(String sud){
     int pos = 0;
     String character="";
     sudoku = new int[sud.length()/9][sud.length()/9];
     for(int i=0; i<sudoku.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<sudoku.length; j++){
            pos = i*sud.length()/9 + j;
            character = sud.charAt(pos)+"";
            sudoku[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(character); // you forgot this
        }
     }
   }
```

You should also eliminate the space from your input String.

Output :

```
  | 2 5 0 | 0 3 0 | 9 0 1 |
 | 0 1 0 | 0 0 4 | 0 0 0 |
 | 4 0 7 | 0 0 0 | 2 0 8 |
 | 0 0 5 | 2 0 0 | 0 0 0 |
 | 0 0 0 | 0 9 8 | 1 0 0 |
 | 0 4 0 | 0 0 3 | 0 0 0 |
 | 0 0 0 | 3 6 0 | 0 7 2 |
 | 0 7 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 3 |
 | 9 0 3 | 0 0 0 | 6 0 4 |
```